# Ask user for numerical input and return character at that index?

Tags: java, eclipse, indexing, char

I am stumped on how to go about completing this. The script needs to Ask the user for a sentence, tell them the length, return the character at that index, than ask them for a character and give the first location it appears. I just cant figure out how to use the numerical input to find return the character at that index. (I know its probably a simple answer).Everything else works.

```
public class Sentence
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int sentlength;
    int letterenter;
    int lowerinput;
    int letterloc;
    String enterletter;

public void sentence()
{
    System.out.print("Please enter a sentence");
    String originalsent = scan.nextLine();
    sentlength=originalsent.length();

    System.out.println("The sentence is "+sentlength+" charecters long");   
    System.out.println("Please enter a number less than the length of the sentence");
    lowerinput = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter a charecter");
    enterletter = scan.next();
    letterloc = originalsent.indexOf(""+enterletter+"");
    System.out.println(""+letterloc+"");
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Sentence worksheet= new Sentence();
    worksheet.sentence();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this from your question

```
    System.out.print("Please enter a sentence: ");
    String originalsent = scan.nextLine();
    sentlength=originalsent.length();

    System.out.println("The sentence is "+ sentlength +" characters long");   
    System.out.println("Please enter a number less than the length of the sentence: ");
    lowerinput = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The character at index " + lowerinput + " is " + originalsent.charAt(lowerinput));
    System.out.println("Please enter a character: ");
    enterletter = scan.next();
    System.out.println("The first index " + enterletter + " shows up is at " + originalsent.indexOf(enterletter));
```

When run outputs the following

```
Please enter a sentence: the cow flew over the moon
The sentence is 26 charecters long
Please enter a number less than the length of the sentence: 
5
The character at index 5 is o
Please enter a charecter: 
o
The first indext o shows up is at 5
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was simple. It was my way of putting it(formatting). Thst messed me up

Comment: awesome! feel free to mark this as the answer if it did solve your issue, that way it closes the question

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy :

```
System.out.println(originalsent.charAt(lowerinput));
```

Comment: I was so close. The extra parenthese was my problem! Thanks!